# Replace Modernizr mq for ie8

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I would like to know how to replace Modernizr mq for ie8 ?

For example. Replace that :

```
Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 480px)')
```

Because I use some jquery code for media queries and Modernizr seems not to run under ie8

Something like $(window).width(); run ?

Comment: why do you want to replace that for ie8?

Comment: Because Modernizr mq didn't run under ie8 no ?

Comment: Modernizr.mq definetly works in ie8. What issue are you having?

Comment: @Patrick which version of Modernizr run with ie8 ?

Comment: every version works. What issue are you having?